# Adjust file created date value for date between evaluation using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to look at the file created date instead of the current date and add 6 days so my between code will work properly.

```
var dateFrom = file.getDateCreated();
var dateTo = new Date();

dateTo.setDate(dateTo.getDate() + 6).toString();

var dateCheck = new Date();

dateCheck.setDate(dateCheck.getDate()).toString();

var from = Date.parse(dateFrom);
var to   = Date.parse(dateTo);
var check = Date.parse(dateCheck );

if((check <= to && check >= from))      
    //  alert("do something");
```

I have made a few attempts

```
var dateTo = (file.getDateCreated() + 7).toString();//failed attempt 1
var dateTo = new Date();
dateTo.setDate(dateTo.file.getDateCreated() + 6).toString();//failed attempt 2
var dateTo = new Date();
dateTo.setDate(dateTo.file.getDateCreated() + 6);//failed attempt 3
```

I am hoping someone can help me learn how to find success.
Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code determines whether today's date is at or past a target date.  The target date is 6 days past the file creation date:

```
function olderThan() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('Your file ID');
  var myFileDate = file.getDateCreated();
  var creationDate = new Date(myFileDate);

  var now = new Date();
  var dateTo = new Date();
  dateTo.setDate(creationDate.getDate() + 6);

  if (now >= dateTo) {
    Logger.log('its older than 6 days old');
  };
};
```